# In a Google spreadsheet, how do I list unique items, modified by a regexp?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, regexextract

I have a Google spreadsheet with items and prices.  Column `D` has the prices, column `C` has item names, some of which contain multiple words.  When an item has multiple words, only the first one is really significant.

What I'd like to achieve is this:

1. Process the item list to strip off anything after the non-alpha character,
2. SORT(UNIQUE()) the results,
3. SUM() all the items that were matched to create this new list.

I will then generate a pie chart (this is food, after all) with the results.  So for example, I might have:

```
  1    C             | D
  -------------------+------------
  2    Cheese        | $9.08
  3    Milk, 2L      | $3.89
  4    Avocado       | $0.99
  5    Avocado 3/$5  | $5.00
  6    Apples Fuji   | $2.75
  7    Avocado       | $1.49
  8    Milk 4L       | $4.75
  9    Apples        | $2.25
```

The end result will be:

```
  Cheese   | $9.08
  Milk     | $8.64
  Avocado  | $7.48
  Apples   | $5.00
```

I know that I can use `REGEXEXTRACT()` to parse an individual field:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(C3; "^([A-Za-z]+)")
```

returns `Milk`, as I would expect.  As well, I know that I can add up totals for a column using `FILTER()`:

```
  L                   | M
  --------------------+----------
  =UNIQUE( C2:C )     | =SUM( FILTER( D$2:D; L2=C$2:C ) )
  =CONTINUE(C2, 2, 1) | =SUM( FILTER( D$2:D; L3=C$2:C ) )
  ...
```

But I want to combine these, and add up the totals of the items as modified by `REGEXEXTRACT()`.  I was hoping I'd be able to do something like:

```
=UNIQUE( REGEXEXTRACT( C2:C; "^([A-Za-z]+)" ) )
```

and

```
=SUM( FILTER( D$2:D; L2=REGEXEXTRACT(C$2:C, "^([A-Za-z]+)") ) )
```

But when presented with a range, the `REGEXEXTRACT()` function delivers just a string, not an array.  This is confirmed, because when I try the formula:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(UNIQUE(C2:C); "^([A-Za-z]+)")
```

the error I get is "**Not a string: Cheese**".

So my question is ... How do I make this work?

Do I need to make a "scratch" worksheet as a bridge?  Is it possible to `REGEXEXTRACT()` each element of a `UNIQUE()` result set within a formula?

Comment: Your list is a bit in-homogeneous. Milk is listed as `Milk, 2L` and `Milk 4L`. If you normalize in the first place, then the data is much more consistent; `Item Description` + `, ` + `Remark`. This way you can use the `SPLIT` function, in combination with the `INDEX` function to extract the first result.  
Come to think of it, the package unit (1L, 2L, 4L, 3/5$) can/must be noted separately, for reasons of inventory listing, cost price calculation.

Comment: Where you able to apply the solution @AdamL provided? If yes, then please mark the answer as best answered.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to "normalise" the data first:

`=ArrayFormula(IF({1,0};IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A;"^([a-zA-Z]+)"));B2:B))`

and then you can actually wrap this directly in a [QUERY](https://support.google.com/drive/table/25273?hl=en&ref_topic=1361471) function to produce the desired output:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(IF({1,0};IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A;"^([a-zA-Z]+)"));B2:B);"select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 != '' group by Col1 label sum(Col2) ''";0))`

You can even output a header row as well:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(IF({1,0};IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A;"^([a-zA-Z]+)"));B2:B);"select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 != '' group by Col1 label Col1 'Food Item', sum(Col2) 'Total'";0))`

Comment: Can you explain what `IF({1,0}` does?